# How do I setup the Login Page to work with requireLogin?

Tags: templating, singles

I want to create a login page.  It would be a Single.

The URI is set to login.  So how do I name and map the twig file?

I tried:

- creating a login folder under templates.
- naming the twig file either `login.twig` or `index.twig`
- setting the template location to `login/login.twig` or `login/index`

Neither approach worked.

How do I setup a login page so that when I use `requireLogin` the login page is in the right location for `loginPath`.  At the bare minimum, where is the easiest location to place the login path?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify Craft 2 or 3, but I'm pretty sure this answer applies to both.

The template should live at `templates/login/index.twig` or `templates/login.twig`. Craft will resolve to both of them.

I tested this on a fresh Craft Pro install and created a Single with a template path of `login`.  There is a `templates/login.twig` with the login example here: https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/examples/login-form.html and a `templates/test.twig` that only has `{% requireLogin %}` in it.

I logged out of Craft, then went to `mysite.com/test` in a browser and was successfully redirected to `mysite.com/login` that rendered the example login template.